# Structuring an International Website

Tags: wordpress, url, structure

I have a Wordpress website which has multiple products serving 2 countries but it could be expanded to more countries in the future. The problem I am having is that there are some products that are available in both countries and some products which are country specific. Think of these products as product pages like the Ipad page on the Apple website: http://www.apple.com/ipad/ not as like shopping cart products.

So what I am thinking is having 2 seperate landing pages where based on the users IP it directs them to either the Australian or American landing page. It's easy for me to envisage how the country specific products will work as they can just be child pages of the Australia or American landing page and I can assign them an Australian or American page template where the Australian or American navigation menu is shown. BUT how do I manage the product pages which are common without having to duplicate the content. Because let's say for product X which is available in both countries I can't assign the page both page template files - it needs to have 1 nav menu.

How can I go about this or am I thinking about this the wrong way. How would a company like Apple handle this as they have identical product pages as shown below:

http://www.apple.com/au/ipad/
http://www.apple.com/uk/ipad/

They obviously have the advantage that their nav items are the same, but I do see in the footer there is some country specific differences.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Possibly look at the WordPress Multilingual Plugin and look closer at the eCommerce section - https://wpml.org/features/. Generally though this question is way too broad for SO and I'm flagging to close.

Comment: Hi James, Yeah WPML is not really a solution to my issue. WPML is more around translating a page but I am talking about having an identical page but with different navigations. Is there a better place to ask this kind of question?